# Can "words" ever have multiple parts of speech?

Tags: parts-of-speech, dictionary, annotated-data

I am considering the design of database schemas for various word types, and wondering how the properties work. For example, it appears that a [wordnet entry](https://github.com/globalwordnet/schemas/blob/master/example.json) has 1 `partOfSpeech` and 1 lemma. But I don't know if it differs elsewhere. Likewise, the Oracc Akkadian dataset has entries with multiple forms and multiple senses, with senses having multiple forms, but all have 1 part of speech. So not sure.

For this question I don't need a complete database schema, just focusing on part of speech:

Can a word have more than one part of speech? Or should an entry equal 1 part of speech? I know the word "tear" is 2 unrelated meanings, with at least 2 major verb meanings, etc.. But that is slightly different, what I'm wondering if outside of English linguists say "this entry or word has multiple parts of speech". Maybe because people disagree what part of speech it is, or it is otherwise unclear, or perhaps based on its role in the sentence it could be different parts.

Basically wondering if each entry should be tied to just 1, or many.

Comment: First, define "word".

Comment: Second, define "part of speech". Or at least, list the possible parts of speech in human language.

Answer (score 1):

Japanese has several types of adjectives: *i*-adjectives, *na*-adjectives, and others. Japanese also has nouns. Some words, in different syntactical contexts, can be used as nouns and *na*-adjectives.

(Difference between nouns and *na*-adjectives is mostly in that pure nouns can be used with case particles (e.g. が (*ga*), の (*no*)), while *na*-adjectives cannot.)

E.g. [静か](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9D%99%E3%81%8B) (*sizuka*) ("quiet, silent") is usually used as *na*-adjective, but it is used as noun ("quietness, silentness, tranquillity") in name of certain [selenographic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/selenographic) region: [静かの海](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9D%99%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E6%B5%B7) (Sizuka no Umi) = "[Mare Tranquillitatis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_Tranquillitatis)".

Answer (score 0):

There are some words that have arguably more than one part of speech. I am thinking of *contractions* like German *im* (<*in dem*) or Italian *nella* (<*in la*), both meaning "in the", accidentally. In practical annotation one usually creates a special part of speech tag for the contractions (and different ones for different types of contractions, if necessary), but one can also argue that they just should have the sum of the part of speech from their components. Another approach to contractions is splitting them into their parts while lemmatising and continue with part of speech on the lemma level.